# Minecraft speedrun tips

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, speedrun

Does anyone have any good minecraft speedrun tips? Many have been trying speedruns, but always lag behind on time (including myself), probably due to unneccessary stuff they did, so I was wondering if anyone could provide some tips?

Comment: watch really good speedrunners on Youtube or Twitch, see what they do differently than you do, and practice skills. The top speedrunners spend a lot of time practicing specific skills, like bastion routing, portal building, etc, over and over. There are maps available for practicing various skills.

Answer (score 3):

## Basic outline to speedrunning

---

**1. Gather Basic Supplies**

Chop some trees and mine some stone. Then, craft a stone axe and stone pickaxe. If you come across chickens, kill them to gather feathers, which are needed later in the run.

---

**2. Find a Village**

Once you have an axe and a pickaxe, look for a village near your spawn location. If it takes too long to find a village due to bad RNG, it may be quicker to restart the run.

---

**3. Gather Iron Ingots**

To progress to the next phase of the run, you will need 4 iron ingots. There are two ways to quickly find iron:

- Kill the Iron Golem in the village.
- Find the Desert Temple and open the treasure chest at the bottom.

The Golem route is quicker. However, the Desert Temple route has a chance of spawning gold ingots, which are needed later in the run.

During this step, you can also loot houses in the village to find beds, which are needed to kill the Ender Dragon quickly.

---

**4. Craft a Bucket and Find a Lava Pool**

Once you have the iron ingots, craft an iron bucket. The bucket is needed to carry lava and water for crafting obsidian blocks. You can usually find a lava pool in the desert, or if you come across one by luck.

---

**5. Create a Nether Portal**

Use the bucket to splash water over lava to create obsidian blocks. Place the blocks in the shape of a doorway to create a nether portal.

[image]

---

**6. Gather Gold**

Once you reach the Nether, there are several tasks you need to complete to progress. The first one is the easiest: roam around and gather enough gold ore to craft about 40 gold ingots. Trade the ingots later to acquire ender pearls.

[image]

---

**7. Find a Nether Fortress and Gather Blaze Rods**

Scout around the Nether until you find a nether fortress. In addition to containing chests with valuable items, the nether fortress can have a blaze spawner. Blazes are enemies that drop blaze rods. These can be broken down into blaze powder, one of the ingredients needed to craft ender eyes.

---

**8. Trade for Ender Pearls**

The Nether is home to Piglins, neutral NPCs that trade with the player. Trade gold ingots for ender pearls, which are the second ingredient for crafting ender eyes. You’re not guaranteed an ender pearl from each trade, so collect at least 40 gold ingots to get 12 ender pearls.

---

**9. Craft the Ender Eyes**

You will need 12 blaze powders and 12 ender pearls to make 12 ender eyes. You will need the eyes later to activate the end portal.

---

**10. Prepare for the End Fight**

To beat the Ender Dragon, you need a bow, around 40 arrows, and 5-6 beds.

Kill spiders to gather cobwebs, which you can then turn into string. Combine string with sticks to craft a bow.

Arrows are made from flint, sticks, and feathers. Gather feathers by killing chickens in the village, flint by mining shoal blocks near water, and sticks from cutting down trees.

There are two ways to acquire beds:

- Craft them from wool and wooden planks. Acquire wool by using shears to shave sheep.
- Steal them from houses in the village. Use tnt to blow up houses and gather beds quickly. Or you can simply mine them yourself.

---

**11. Use an Ender Eye to Find the Stronghold**

Ender eyes can be used to triangulate the location of the stronghold, the place where the end portal resides. To do this, throw an ender eye in the air, and note the direction in which it is looking. This is the direction you need to follow to find the stronghold. Repeat the process three times from different angles to zero in on the location of the stronghold.

[image]

---

**12. Go through the End Portal**

Once you have the equipment for the fight, go back to the stronghold and look for the portal room. It spawns at random, so it might take a while. Then, place the 12 ender pearls in the 12 slots and jump through the portal.

---

**13. Fight the Ender Dragon**

The Ender Dragon fight has two phases. In the first phase, you will need to use the bow and arrow to shoot at crystals on top of pillars to make the dragon fly closer to the ground.

Once you have the dragon in range, quickly drop a bed, and then attempt to sleep. Trying to sleep while in the End dimension will cause the bed to explode and deal massive damage to anything near it. To prevent it from damaging you, place a random block between yourself and the bed.

Detonating the bed near the dragon’s head will deal the most damage. It usually takes around 5-6 beds to kill the dragon. The run is complete the moment the dragon drops dead.

*Congratulations, you’ve completed your first Minecraft speedrun!*

---

Credits to [Glimpse.me](https://glimpse.me/blog/how-to-speedrun-minecraft/)

*Note that the steps have been edited and moved around a bit*

---

## Some Tips

---

1. Avoid getting diamonds, especially if you are aiming for a low time
2. Build nether portals like [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=e29kkvLwdCA), which is argubly one of the fastest ways

---

More tips coming up!